# On my webserver, opinion/advice on automatically adding php-fcgi users?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, automation, php-fpm

I am not 100% sure of how to actually add users, however I am choosing Apache over other backends finally and that may be easier.

From what I can gather, adding an fcgi user would mean adding a Linux user account (i.e. I may even do net_foobar or org_foobar rather than some tutorials that say foobar.com which is "dirty") and then of course create a vhost for them, and other fcgi stuff that I may have to do (unsure of yet) to get them to run under the appropriate user.

Would it be valid (in terms of how hosts panels work in the background) to have an automated script to add the user name, with checking of course, and the appropriate vhosts stuff so I do not have to automatically do this each time by hand?

I am likely anticipating a few websites I would like to host for people, programming related, so at least a script I could call and give a single parameter to automate this would be helpful. Unsure if this is really the way to go.

I would prefer not to delegate this task to a hosting control panel, as I do not like third party software.

Comment: I'm not sure how your dislike of third party software has a bearing on whether or not to write a script...

Comment: @womble,  I was thinking of hosting panels, or other various things, I am just not sure I like them doing the vhosts and whatnot without me seeing what exactly they are doing up close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfect task for scripted automation.  Store each vhost in it's own file, so it's easy to add and remove them automatically as needed, script the config and user creation, and you'll save a lot of work (both in having to do it by hand each time, and fixing up the errors you'll inevitably make -- humans are really poor at error-free execution of repetitive tasks).

Comment: You've restored confidence, it us quite simple actually as the pools/vhosts will be a static name, I could even write my own vadmin script or whatnot, and pass `vadmin org_site_about add` or whatnot.